# trying to set Useragent

Tags: python

Im trying to set the useragent in this script.

```
def stream_video(url):
    url = str(url).replace('USERNAME',username).replace('PASSWORD',password)
    liz = xbmcgui.ListItem('', iconImage='DefaultVideo.png', thumbnailImage=icon)
    liz.setInfo(type='Video', infoLabels={'Title': '', 'Plot': ''})
    liz.setProperty('IsPlayable','true')
    liz.setPath(str(url))
    xbmcplugin.setResolvedUrl(int(sys.argv[1]), True, liz)
```

Everything I tried fails to send the useragent I set, anyone knows how I would pass an useragent in this?

Ive tried

```
def stream_video(url):
    url = str(url).replace('USERNAME',username).replace('PASSWORD',password)
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', UA)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(SmartRedirectHandler())
    f = opener.open(req)
    link = f.url
    liz = xbmcgui.ListItem('', iconImage='DefaultVideo.png', thumbnailImage=icon)
    liz.setInfo(type='Video', infoLabels={'Title': '', 'Plot': ''})
    liz.setProperty('IsPlayable','true')
    liz.setPath(str(url))
    headers = ({'User-Agent': 'Kodi/21.1 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; p212 Build/MHC19J) Android/6.0.1 Sys_CPU/armv8l App_Bitness/32 Version/21.1-Git:2017-11-20-c327c53-dirty'})
    xbmcplugin.setResolvedUrl(int(sys.argv[1]), True, liz)
```

Comment: ok, so i managed to get the UA to change. but when openining the streams, they're not playing, a packetsniff says the stream is being downloaded. am i missing something?

Comment: def getURL( url ):
    try:
        txdata = None
        txheaders = {
            'User-Agent': 'Kodi/21.1 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; p212 Build/MHC19J) Android/6.0.1 Sys_CPU/armv8l App_Bitness/32 Version/21.1-Git:2017-11-20-c327c53-dirty',
            }
        req = urllib2.Request(url, txdata, txheaders)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        link=response.read()
        response.close()
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        error = 'Error code: '+ str(e.code)
        return False
    else:
        return link

Comment: def stream_video(url):
 url = str(url).replace('USERNAME',username).replace('PASSWORD',password)
 liz = xbmcgui.ListItem('', iconImage='DefaultVideo.png', thumbnailImage=icon)
 liz.setInfo(type='Video', infoLabels={'Title': '', 'Plot': ''})
 liz.setProperty('IsPlayable','true')
 liz.setPath(str(getURL(url)))
 xbmcplugin.setResolvedUrl(int(sys.argv[1]), True, liz)